# Import WMS link from KML file to QGIS not working

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, aster

I've downloaded a kml file from here: https://gbank.gsj.jp/madas/map/index.html
to look at some aerial photography. I've clicked 'kml' and it downloads a kml file. When I drag this into QGIS it displays the shapefile of the image boundaries, and raster that doesn't display anything.

I then opened the kml file using notepad++ and can then view the metadata and what apears to be a WMS link. When I create a new WMS link in QGIS and import this url: https://aster.geogrid.org/atlm/2309121819382309139003?service=wms&request=getmap&version=1.3.0&layers=default&crs=epsg:4326&format=image/png&transparent=true

it loads the layer into QGIS but nothing displays. I've tried all the different options before clicking 'load' after connecting the WMS link, and tried WFS.

Why can't I see the image?

Edit: I get this error on the raster file (invisible) that imports when I drag the kml file in:
IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: GDALWMS: Unable to download block 0, 0. URL: HTTP status code: 0, error: (null). Add the HTTP status code to to ignore this error (see http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html).,IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: GDALWMS: Unable to download block 0, 0. URL: HTTP status code: 0, error: (null). Add the HTTP status code to to ignore this error (see http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html).
IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: GDALWMS: Unable to download block 0, 0. URL: HTTP status code: 0, error: (null). Add the HTTP status code to to ignore this error (see http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html).

Comment: `https://aster.geogrid.org/atlm/2309121819382309139003?service=wms&request=getmap&version=1.3.0&layers=default&crs=epsg:4326&format=image/png&transparent=true` doesn't supply sufficient information to fetch a map image; you are missing several parameters, like bounding box, width and height.  Case is also wrong for some of the parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

The server is somehow misconfigured. The GetMap URL that is shows in the GetCapabilities https://aster.geogrid.org/atlm/2309121819382309139003?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities does not work. Bypass that in the QGIS connection configuration

[image]

This setting makes it work for me

[image]

You have included too much to the URL of the WMS connection. I am not sure if it makes trouble, but this is all you need:
`https://aster.geogrid.org/atlm/2309121819382309139003`

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it now to display.